# Bug or not? Visual Studio 2013 preview std::vector initializer list with std::string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector, uniform-initialization

Finally they did it. MSVC12 compiler now allows uniform initialization. But I found, that it works differently than GNU GCC 4.8.1 with `-std=C++11` flag.

Consider this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Data
{
    Data(const std::string& name, int x):
        m_Name(name),
        m_X(x)
    {}

    std::string m_Name;
    int m_X;
};

std::vector<Data> datas = 
{
    Data("one", 1),
    Data("two", 2),
    Data("three", 3),
};

int main()
{
    for(auto it = datas.begin(); it != datas.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << it->m_Name << " "  << it->m_X << "\n";

}
```

Result with GCC (as expected):

```
one 1
two 2
three 3
```

([ideone link](http://ideone.com/P1USOk))

Result with MSVC12:

```
 1
 2
 3
```

like strings hasn't been initialized.

Questions:

- Does my code snippet syntax is correct according to C++11 standard?
- Does GCC behavior is standard or is it some kind of extension?
- Does MSVC behavior is standard or is it a bug?

Comment: This is a bug in MSVC.

Comment: Are you *sure* you are posting the correct output? The GCC version looks quite suspicious too.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, I've tested with `mingw-w64-4.8.1`. Also added link to ideone. But please feel free to share any thoughts, because I want to start use that feature in my main projects' code.

Comment: So GCC somehow invents "two" and "three" where it should be "one"? Then there is also a bug in MinGW.

Comment: Whoops! Copypazd is evil =) Please check http://ideone.com/P1USOk for more issues

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz ["definitely"](http://www.d-e-f-i-n-i-t-e-l-y.com), _please!_

Comment: @gx_ if I thought it's definitely a bug, I'd definitely spell it that way. That's a defiant bug though. :)

Comment: if you really want to test C++11 conformance, why not drop the `Data(...)` in favor of `{ ... }` (initalizer-list) and also use a ranged-for loop? e.g. [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1491a3f0e7c4d78739907ccbae5a0ff5-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc)

Comment: @TemplateRex: FWIW, it's also broken after making those changes.

Answer (score 2):

This may have been a bug in VS2013 Preview. The output of the binary generated by the current VS2013 RC is consistent with g++.

Comment: Yay! They did it! =))